# How to copy elements with selenium after clicking and assigning to variable with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape last day's proxies from https://checkerproxy.net . I'm able to click with selenium to proxies but I can not copy them and assign to a variable(such as x) or list in python. I can not figure it out how to apply copy and paste keys

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

path1 = "./chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path1)
driver.get("https://checkerproxy.net/")

temp = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body")
elem = temp.get_attribute('innerHTML')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='block archive f_right']//li[1]").click()
time.sleep(20) # waiting for loading of proxies

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='find_result']").click()
#elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c')
#x = elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

Comment: why use keys if you can basically scrape the value of it and assign to a variable in your program?

Comment: I can not repeat this process every day. Also, I'll check them still online or dead

Comment: there's a cron job to do it for you every day

Comment: I'm also using schedule module. The problem is not getting the proxies. I need to take these proxies with selenium webdriver and checking their availability. After than using my another crawling script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below to get required proxies:

```
proxies = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='find_result']").get_attribute('value')
```

to get those values as list:

```
proxies = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='find_result']").get_attribute('value').split('\n')
```

You can also remove `time.sleep(20)` with below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

proxies = wait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='find_result']").get_attribute('value').strip()).split('\n')
```

Comment: Welcome! You can try updated answer to avoid using `time.sleep()`